# How do I filter a loop based on multiple computed properties in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a search filter using Vue2 JS. It works fine when searching for just the title of a blog. However, how do I get it to show results based on the location as well?

This is because the input used by the search may be a general keyword search or at least set to search against **title** and **location** etc.

I have;

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            search:'',
            blogs: [
              { 
                title: 'Northern Towns' ,
                location: 'Leeds'
              },
              { 
                title: 'Things to do in Leeds' ,
                location: 'Yorkshire'
              },
              { 
                title: 'Visit the beach',
                location: 'Cornwall'
              }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredBlogs:function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
              return blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search);
              return blog.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: the secord return statement 'return blog.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search);' is unreachable. Do you always want to search by a title prop and a location prop?

Comment: For now. Yes. As a user may be interested in things to do with Yorkshire. Therefore, there would be two results based on the data. However, if the filter is set to search only against the title they would only see one result. This I am looking to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this, you just need to add `OR` in searching whether to search location or title.

```js
   const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            search: '',
             blogs: [
              { 
                title: 'Northern Towns' ,
                location: 'Leeds'
              },
              { 
                title: 'Things to do in Leeds' ,
                location: 'Yorkshire'
              },
              { 
                title: 'Visit the beach',
                location: 'Cornwall'
              }
            ]
        },
    computed: {
        filteredBlogs:function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
              return blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||  blog.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
        <label>
            Search name: <input type="text" v-model='searchString'>
        </label> <br>
            <li v-for='item in filteredBlogs' :key='item.id' class="my-list-item">
                {{item.title}}
            </li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have options that are indicating what type of a search a user selected then it could look like:

```
computed: {
        filteredBlogs:function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
               const matchedByTitle = blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search)
               const matchedByLocation = blog.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search)
               if (this.searchByTitle) {
                 return matchedByTitle
               }
               if (this.searchByLocation) {
                 return matchedByLocation
               }
               if (this.searchByTitleAndLocation) {
                 return matchedByTitle || matchedByLocation
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps me understand and learn. The solution with the logical operators (two pipes) seems to work great! Thank you so much for your valued assistance.